# No view for jenkins plugin in eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, plugins

I installed the latest eclipse version and also the plugin: Mylyn Builds Connector: (Hudson/Jenkins 1.17.0.v20200730-1155 org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn). With my older eclipse version I could open the MyLyn Builds view to view the results of the jenkins builds, but with the new version of eclipse I could not find any view with displays this.

Thanks for hints!

Comment: Does it work with the nightly build (_Help > Install New Software..._ working with the update site [`https://ci.eclipse.org/mylyn/job/GitHub-mylyn-Orga/job/org.eclipse.mylyn/job/main/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.eclipse.mylyn-site/target/repository/`](https://ci.eclipse.org/mylyn/job/GitHub-mylyn-Orga/job/org.eclipse.mylyn/job/main/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.eclipse.mylyn-site/target/repository/))?

Comment: Thanks that worked. But now I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null. I enter password and user and for the server the new http address, which worked for the old jenkins server. I could ping the new server. Any idea?

Comment: Does it work with the Jenkins server `https://ci.eclipse.org/mylyn/`? Anything in the error log (go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_)? Consider to report it [here](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn), best with a pull request. ;)

Comment: Hi, the jenkins server for mylyn is working. Maybe there is something in our network that protect the acccess. We tried also the anynomous setting for the server and the client, but it doesn't work. Access via firefox browser is working. Do the client need special ports?

Comment: Do you get something like https://ci.eclipse.org/mylyn/api when you add `api` to your URL?

Comment: I enter the url in the form of http://xxx.yy.zz.a:8080 and get: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
 at org.apache.http.util.Args.containsNoBlanks(Args.java:81)
 at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:80)

Comment: If I add /api the response is: Caused by: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.HudsonResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource '/api/api/xml' does not exist,    http://xxx.yy.zz.a:8080/api/xml in a browser works.